# What will happen to the programs(purchased games, Word, etc.) I already have on my computer if I change from Windows to Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I am concerned about how changing my operating system will affect the programs I have already downloaded while using my Windows 7 operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing Kubuntu side-by-side Windows 7 than all Windows programs would be just fine (as it is).

If you are installing Kubuntu on-top-of Windows 7 than you will be left with a fresh Kubuntu System. But I m sure you will still have license for those programs, but many of those programs will not be available inherently on Linux so you will need to use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) to emulate them in Linux enviornment.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "side-by-side" and "on-top-of"